# css selecting element on an added class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Following markup is given:

```
    <header id="main-header">
        <div class="container clearfix et_menu_container">
            <div class="logo_container">
            </div>
            <!-- .logo_container -->
            <div id="et-top-navigation">
                <nav id="top-menu-nav">
                    <ul id="top-menu" class="nav">
                        ... ...
                        <li id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item">
                            <a href="hello">Abteilungen</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- #et-top-navigation -->
        </div>
        <!-- .container -->
        <div class="tg-submenu">
            <div class="tg-submenu__abteilungen">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .submenu -->
    </header>
```

the #menu-item-103 gets an added class (et-hover) by the use of js, when hovering the item. Beside that the .tg-submenu should become visible when the user hovers the #menu-item-103. Can this be achieved by css (eventually in connection of the added class et-hover on the li element) or is additional javascript required for this solution?

Comment: I can repost it as answer, but no, this is not possible with CSS. You need JS for this task.

Comment: Or rearrange the html so that the tg-submenu is in the menu-item-103.

Comment: yes thought so, I already tried different solutions. Sad story. For sure post it as answer, you get the solved button :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible with CSS. You need JS for this task. CSS is limited with things like `:hover`, `:active`, `:focus` pseudo-classes. It also have `+` and `~` combinators, which can be used together with pseudo-classes, but it still less powerful then JS, and isn't helpful in your specific case.

Comment: I don't get why you've been downvoted, so have an upvote for a correct answer.

Comment: Probably because my question was a bit improved since last downvote)

Comment: Your original answer was just as valid :)